# Problem in server side execution in page dir

Tags: authentication, mongoose, next.js, next-auth

1-save coockies and session in client
2-authentication with that with next-auth
3-check session in api (when i want save data in mongoDB the first i check session , but when i log session with getSession({req})
return null
but i open api/auth/session is true i can see info from user
in last version is ok but on new version had problem

I expect to get the relevant data from the server when I get the session, but it returns null .[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9trNT.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQzjg.jpg)